# Techniques to find matrix inverses of general classes of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose you're given some general description of an $n\times n$ matrix, and asked to find its inverse.  By "general description" I mean that the matrix can be described in one or more sentences, and this description holds for arbitrary $n$.

For example, you may be told to find the inverse of $A$, where $A$ has ones on the diagonal and superdiagonal, and zeros elsewhere.  Or to find the inverse of $B$ where $B$ has ones on and above the diagonal, and zeros elsewhere.  What are the general techniques that may be used in these cases?

My naive approach would be to find explicit inverses for a few small values of $n$ (say, $n = 2, 3, 4$) then try to extrapolate a pattern from these instances.  Alternatively, I could see how one may write such matrices (at least in the simple examples given) as a product of elementary row operation matrices, but then I'm not sure how to convert this product into an explicit matrix.  Perhaps something can be done using the eigen-decomposition?

Comment: I don't know whether the two examples you mention are typical of what you need to do, but in both cases, you have to solve a system represented by an augmented matrix $[M|I],$ which is already in row-echelon form.  It is not hard to see what the fully-reduced form is going to look like for general $n$ in either of these cases.

Comment: In general you want to determine if your matrix has full rank. If so then a true inverse will exist and can be found using the method in the above comment. If not then you can construct a pseudo inverse using singular value decomposition, or other types of generalized inverses. In short the method used will depend on the matrix.

Comment: For simplicity let's say, as in the above two examples, that the matrix is full rank.  So are you suggesting the same approach as what I've written?  Solve the explicit inverse for some reasonable $n$ (using whatever approach you like, e.g. by solving the augmented matrix) and try to reason out what the general solution would be?  I was just curious whether there was a more systematic approach.

Comment: There are often specialized methods for solving, inverting, and/or finding eigenvalues of matrices with a particular structure.  For example, there are specialized techniques for tridiagonal matrices, circulant matrices, and Toeplitz matrices.  If you will be dealing with lots of such matrices, it's probably worth learning those techniques.